# Why does the code below only print the first char of a String?

Tags: java, printing, print-job-control

I'm programming a password calling system, and I'm having trouble to print the callsign. Basically it's supposed to print a String like "C1234", but it only prints the "C" whithout the following numbers.

Already tried messing with the DocFlavor and InputStream Types, however every time it prints the problem repeats itself.

This is the printing function.

```
public void PrintSenha()
    {
        String impressora = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService().getName();
        System.out.println("Default Printer: "+impressora);

        PrintService servico = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();

        String senha = "C2450";

        byte[] dados;

        try {
            dados = senha.getBytes();

            PrintRequestAttributeSet  pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
            pras.add(new Copies(1));

            DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE;
            Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(dados, flavor, null);
            DocPrintJob job = servico.createPrintJob();

            job.print(doc, pras); 

        } catch (PrintException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Operacoes.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            System.err.print("Print Exception"+ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.TEXT_PLAIN_UTF_8`?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Just Tried. It catch sun.print.PrintJobFlavorException: invalid flavor

Comment: It could be that your printer does not accept plain text documents and you need to convert the text to PostScript or something similar.